# Are tuples in Python immutable?

Tags: python, tuples, immutability

It says

> A tuple can not be changed in any way once it is created.

But when I do the following:

```
t1=(4,5,8,2,3)
t1=t1+(7,1)
print(t1)
```

the tuple is changing to `(4, 5, 8, 2, 3, 7, 1)`; why is that? What is really meant by "tuples are immutable"?

Comment: "No tuples were harmed in the execution of this code"

Comment: `t=2; t=t+5` is not changing the number 2 to 7, but creates a new number ;-)

Comment: @tdelaney: I am afraid the life of the original tuples will not be very long after this piece of code. Programmers seldom stop to think about the old objects their program no longer needs. The old objects are not sent to any elderly care facility...

Answer (score 10):

Yes, tuples are immutable; once created, they cannot be changed. `t1=t1+(7,1)` creates a *new tuple* and assigns it to the name `t1`. It **does not** change the tuple object originally referenced by that name.

Demo:

```
>>> t = (1, 2, 3)
>>> id(t)
4365928632
>>> t = t + (4, 5)
>>> id(t)
4354884624 # different id, different object
```

Comment: jsut one remark for the OP: You can think of the variable name as a label which is sticked to the tuple - and your assignment just put the same label to a new tupel.

Answer (score 3):

No tuple is changing in your code. The [name](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) `t1` is made to refer to a new, distinct tuple. The original tuple object never changed, you just stopped using it.

Answer (score 2):

yes they are immutable

```
t1 = t1 + (7,1)
```

Is creating a new tuple ... not modifying the old one

try

```
t1[0] = 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically when you call `t1=t1+(7,1)`, you are **reassigning** `t1` to a different memory location. What python means by immutable, is that you can't change them by slicing:

```
>>> t1=(4,5,8,2,3)
>>> t1[0] = 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>>
```

Because this creates a new tuple:

```
>>> t1=(4,5,8,2,3)
>>> id(t1)
4467745808
>>> t1 = t1+(9,)
>>> id(t1)
4468302112
>>>
```

As you can see with lists, they **keep the `id`**:

```
>>> lst = [4, 5, 8, 2, 3]
>>> id(lst)
4468230480
>>> lst[0] = 6
>>> id(lst)
4468230480
>>>
```

That is python's definition of **immutability**.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say Yes.
Python tuples have a surprising trait: they are immutable, but their values may change. This may happen when a tuple holds a ref. to any mutable object, such as a dict, list...

```
>>> t1 = ('Bangalore', ['HSR', 'Koramangala'])
>>> print(t1)
('Bangalore', ['HSR', 'Koramangala'])
>>> print(id(t1)) # ID of tuple
4619850952

>>> place = t1[1]
>>> place.append('Silk Board')  # Adding new value to the list
>>> print(t1) 
('Bangalore', ['HSR', 'Koramangala', 'Silk Board'])
# Surprisingly tuple changed, let's check the ID
>>> print(id(t1)) # No change in the ID of tuple
4619850952

>>> print(t1[0])
Bangalore
>>> print(id(t1[0])) # ID of tuple's first element
4641176176
>>> print(id(t1[1])) # ID of tuple's second element (List)
4639158024
# These are the ref. id's of the tuple

>>> place.append('Agara')
>>> print(t1) 
('Bangalore', ['HSR', 'Koramangala', 'Silk Board', 'Agara'])
>>> print(id(t1))
4619850952
# Still no change, are they Immutable ??

>>> print(id(t1[1])) # The tuple having a ref. of Mutable object
4639158024
```

In the above example the id's of tuple and list didn't change. This is happening due to reference which is mapped to the tuple not the value.